# Why did they call it the Knight Bus?

Tags: harry-potter, knight-bus

> The need for some form of transportation that could be used safely and discreetly by the underage or the infirm had been felt for a while and many suggestions had been made (sidecars on taxi-style broomsticks, carrying baskets slung under Thestrals) all of them vetoed by the Ministry. Finally, Minister for Magic Dugald McPhail hit upon the idea of imitating the Muggles’ relatively new ‘bus service’ and in 1865, the Knight Bus hit the streets.

Why was it called the Knight Bus, in universe (I'm happy enough that OoU Rowling has a penchant for bad puns)?

Comment: Because it is a bus that runs at night and charges through traffic like a knight in shining armour?

Comment: I love how Mac here took the quote from the Pottermore article and we are throwing in other lines right from it back at him.

Comment: @Skooba yah, bit embarassing. TBF i didn't really take the quote from Pottermore, it came from another question (didn't even know where the quote came from, I just hoped it wasn't wiki-rubbish). Still embarrasing :P (also you shoulda kept your answer up! Quick enuff to get away with I think, and rep is well-earnt) EDIT: ffs the two quotes are on the same page even!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### J.K. Rowling's out-of-universe explanation seems to somewhat apply in-universe as well:

> The Knight Bus was so-named because, firstly, knight is a homonym of night, and there are night buses running all over Britain after normal transport stops. Secondly, ‘knight’ has the connotation of coming to the rescue, of protection, and this seemed appropriate for a vehicle that is often the conveyance of last resort.
>   <sub>([Pottermore - Knight Bus](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-knight-bus))</sub>

The two reasons are:

- **Knight is a homonym of night, and there are night buses running all over Britain after normal transport stops.**

  In-universe, the Knight Bus is inspired by Muggle technology as well.

  > The Knight Bus is a relatively modern invention in wizarding society, which sometimes (though it will rarely admit it) takes ideas from the Muggle world.
  >
  > some wizards (mainly pureblood fanatics) announced their intention of boycotting what was dubbed ‘this Muggle-esque outrage’
  >   <sub>([Pottermore - Knight Bus](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-knight-bus))</sub>
- **‘Knight’ has the connotation of coming to the rescue, of protection, and this seemed appropriate for a vehicle that is often the conveyance of last resort.**

  The Knight Bus kind of makes this theme their motto.

  > Welcome to the Knight  Bus, emergency  transport for the stranded witch or wizard. Just stick out your wand hand, step on board, and we can take  you anywhere  you  want  to  go.
  >   <sub>(Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 3 - [text available on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/features/magical-transportation-that-goes-beyond-the-broom))</sub>

Comment: Christ, I hate choosing accepted answers when they all answer from canon. You spelled it out more I guess, so...

Comment: Although the London "night buses" only started in 1913, so if the first leg of the out-of-universe explanation applies in-universe then it's not by normal temporal cause and effect.

Answer (score 26):

Per Pottermore - ["The Knight Bus](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-knight-bus)"

> **J.K. Rowling's thoughts**
>
> *The Knight Bus was so-named because, firstly, knight is a homonym of night, and there are night buses running all over Britain after normal transport stops. Secondly, ‘knight’ has the connotation of coming to the rescue, of protection, and this seemed appropriate for a vehicle that is often the conveyance of last resort.*
>
> *The driver and conductor of the Knight Bus in ‘Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban’ are named after my two grandfathers, Ernest and Stanley.*

Comment: @Skooba - A day late and a dollar short, as my sainted granny used to say.

Comment: Is this in-universe though? Or why Rowling chose OoU to name it that?

Comment: @MacCooper IMO the **in** and **out** of universe explanations would be similar...

Comment: `after normal transport stops` ... what normal (magical) transport is JKR referring to? Does the flue network shut down after a certain time? Is it only possible to apparate between 8 AM and 8 PM? Are brooms only useful for sweeping after last call?

Comment: @MacCooper - In the absence of any word to the contrary, I believe that Skooba is right. This is both the in- and out-of-universe justification.

Comment: @Richard works for me. I'm figuring if Rowling had said anything else on the subject you'd have found it =D

Comment: I had assumed the OP already knew the quote and therefore took longer to post my answer, so I could justify why I was quoting something the OP had specifically excluded.

Comment: FWIW: There are *not* night buses running 'all over Britain', just a few routes in the major cities, eg London. They are usually full of very drunk people, and not regarded as the safest mode of transit...

Comment: @SeanR - Don't forget that JKR lived in London for much of her life. She, like many urban authors seems to think that London = England.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that @Richard - Just putting the note up for clarity for those who may not know that England <> London!

Comment: @SeanR: London, Edinburgh, Manchester, Glasgow, Oxford, Durham, Newcastle, Brighton, Bristol, Nottingham, Derby, Leeds all advertise some night bus services. So "all over Britain" not in the sense of "every bus route in Britain", but in the sense of "many places scattered around Britain". Plus, by analogy with places that do have formal "night bus" services, people may *call* late-night buses the "night bus" even though technically it's just the regular bus running at reduced frequency :-) But sure, they're an urban phenomenon: much of Britain you barely get day buses never mind night.

Comment: @Xantec Very good point, actually. For that matter, I don’t recall any mention in the books that the Knight Bus only runs at night, either. The ‘underage and infirm’ would presumably have needs of transportation during the day as well. Combine this with Steve Jessop’s comment on ibid’s answer, and I would say it’s more likely that the ‘knight rhymes with night’ bit is purely out-of-universe, while the ‘knight in shining armour’ bit is in-universe. Seems unlikely they’d (in-universe) name a 24-hour service after a not yet existing nighttime-only service.